# Angular 2, Event from enum

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a problem I do not know how to make invisible the value 2 of the "Titulo" enum and that when I click on the value "no" (1) of the radio button "existio contacto" of coincidence.component.html is visible

This is coincidence html

```html
  <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <md-card class="cards">
          <span class="title">{{titulo}} </span>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 columns">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="small-6 columns">
                  <span class="subtitle">
    Number matching</span>
                  <span>3333333333</span>
                </div>
                <div class="small-6 columns">
                  <span class="subtitle">
    existio contacto</span>
                  <md-radio-group class="radio-vertical" [(ngModel)]="valorRadio" (change)="opcionNoExistioContacto($event)">
                    <md-radio-button value="0">Yes</md-radio-button>
                    <md-radio-button value="1">No</md-radio-button>
                    <md-radio-button value="2">Yes third</md-radio-button>
                  </md-radio-group>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="small-12 columns">
                <md-select *ngIf="valorRadio == 1" placeholder="Causal" class="select_100">
                  <md-option value="0">Does not answer</md-option>
                  <md-option value="1">
                    Occupied phone</md-option>
                </md-select>
                <md-select *ngIf="valorRadio == 2" placeholder="No Contacto" [(ngModel)]="valorOpcion" class="select_100">
                  <md-option value="0">
                    Third does not provide new contact number but serves as reference</md-option>
                  <md-option value="1">
                    Third does not provide information</md-option>
                </md-select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="valorOpcion == 3 || valorOpcion == 2">
              <div class="small-6 columns">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="small-6 columns">
                    <span>phone</span>
                    <input type="tel" maxlength="10">
                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </md-card>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is coincidence ts

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Output,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MdRadioChange
} from "@angular/material";

import {
  ValorGestionTelefonica
} from "app/dto/datos";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-coincidence',
  templateUrl: './coincidence.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./coincidence.component.css']
})
export class CoincidenceComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() titulo: number;
  @Input() indice: number;
  @Output() evaluarOpciones = new EventEmitter < ValorGestionTelefonica > ();


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  opcionNoExistioContacto(evento: MdRadioChange) {
    if (evento.source) {
      let valor = new ValorGestionTelefonica();
      valor.indice = this.indice;
      valor.valor = evento["value"];

      this.evaluarOpciones.emit(valor);
    }
  }
}
```

This is panel tres html

```html
<app-coincidence *ngFor="let a of titulos; let i = index" [indice]=i [titulo]=a (evaluarOpciones)="evaluarOpciones($event)"></app-coincidence>
```

This is panel tres ts

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  Provider
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ValorGestionTelefonica
} from '../../dto/datos';

enum Titulo {
  'Celular Coincidente con Reconocer' = 1, 'Primer Celular Reconocer' = 2
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel-tres',
  templateUrl: './panel-tres.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel-tres.component.css']
})
export class PanelTresComponent implements OnInit {

  titulos: string[];


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let titulos = Object.keys(Titulo);
    this.titulos = titulos.slice(titulos.length / 2);
    console.log(titulos);
    console.log("titulos");


  }

  evaluarOpciones(valor: ValorGestionTelefonica): void {
    console.log(valor.valor + "--" + valor.indice);
  }

}
```

class ValorGestionTelefonica

```js
export class ValorGestionTelefonica {
  valor: any;
  indice: number;
}
```

Comment: Please make an example plunker showing the behavior you do/don't want

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/sm5yEir9Lq0ZWiJ9yoZF 
I want the second card to be invisible and if I click on "no" it will appear on the second card with the second title on the enum

Comment: Please don't remove all your code like that. Instead if you would like to improve, post a proper [mcve].

Comment: @EDWARDFABIANTAPIEROGOMEZ I'm sorry but I still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. I'm happy to help but I do not understand what you want to do. Can you please provide a simplified example that can clarify what your'e after.

Comment: @JoshuaOhana 
I will explain as explicitly as I can, There are two cards, but they are seen by an "ngFor" that is in "titulo-tres.html" this "ngFor" does it by two values ​​that are in an "enum" that is in the "panel-three, this" enum "Assigning titles for each" card ", what I want to accomplish, is to display originally only the first" card "and the first value of the "enum"and if you click the "No " radio-button, show the second "card" With the second value of the "enum" found in "panel-tres.ts"

Comment: Just posted an answer @EDWARDFABIANTAPIEROGOMEZ thanks for clarifying the question. For future questions I would suggest you 1) rename everything to English, filenames, class names, variables, etc, it would have been much easier to read that way since SO is a global community and 2) create a truly minimal example, most of your code pasted was irrelevant to the actual question, you should try to create as small an example as possible so that it's easier for people to help you

Comment: @JoshuaOhana 
I will take into account your suggestions thank you, additional clarified my question, I thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize your issue to ensure I have it correct

You are iterating across an enum of 2 keys in an ngFor. You want the second to appear only after some event occurs on the first.

1) If the enum is always 2 items long, why bother with any of this? You could very simply just directly code the two elements and tie them around in ngIf or something

```
<coincidence [indice]=1 [titulo]='first title' (click)="showSecond = true"></coincidence>
<coincidence [indice]=2 [titulo]='second title' *ngIf="showSecond></coincidence>
```

2) If your enum is of a dynamic length or you want to manage it programmatically, then I would handle it by putting your titles over in an object which contains a showMe boolean flag. For example,

In your panel-tres.ts

```
let titulosKeys = Object.keys(Titulo);
let titulosList = titulos.slice(titulos.length / 2);
this.titulos = [];
titulosList.forEach(titulo => {

  let showMe;
  if(titulo == 'Celular Coincidente con Reconocer') showMe = true;
  else showMe = false;

  this.titulos.push({
     titulo: titulo,
     showMe: showMe
  });

});
```

then update your coincidence.html template to reflect that change

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="titulo.showMe">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
  <md-card class="cards">
    <span>{{titulo.titulo}}</span>
    <div class="row">
  ...
```

Then capture the click event and change the showMe var of the item you want to show or hide (might need to bubble up the event back to panel-tres via an EventEmitter or something)

You might want to play around with the typings involved but that will get you setup